# Use Tumblr API in Tumblr

Tags: javascript, api, tumblr

I have looked everywhere for this answer - I imagined it would be simple considering all the complicated stuff read about Tumblr API in my infinite google searches.

All I want to do is display in a little box on my tumblr index page the total posts.

e.g. **Total posts:** 689

I have read dozens over stack overflow questions about tumblr api, lots of quora questions too. But none have an answer.

Some contain code such as:

```
<div>Note Total</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://{name}.tumblr.com/api/read/json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var msg =tumblr_api_read;
 var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(msg));
 $('#NoteTotal').append("<br/><br/>" + "this site as " + obj['posts-total'] +" Total         posts.");
</script>
```

but when I put this into my html nothing shows up. I've experimented with lots of other codes but nothing shows up either and I have found no tutorials, not even on the tumblr api documentation to show me how to do it.
The only thing I've managed to do is pull my avatar, by placing http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/david.tumblr.com/avatar/512 in a

```
<img src"">
```

but even that was my own doing, no article told me I had to put it in an image tag to get it to show, so I'm thinking there is a similarly simple way to get a total posts api to show, perhaps someone here can help me.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will also work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://[yourblogname].tumblr.com/api/read/json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var posts = tumblr_api_read['posts-total'] // total posts
var totalposts = "<b>Total posts:</b> ";
document.write(totalposts)
document.write(posts)
</script>
```

Replace `[yourblogname]` with your blog.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to check the JavaScript console for errors. Then you'll get an error message instead of "nothing shows up". [Here's how to open the JavaScript console in Chrome.](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#basic_operation)

Also, the way you used `#NoteTotal` suggests that you don't really know how jQuery and element selectors work. Quick intro: `#something` selects the element with the id `something`, for example, `<div id="something"></div>`.

Moreover, your code above probably doesn't work in your theme because it depends on the JavaScript library jQuery and that your theme doesn't load jQuery, or because you inserted the code before jQuery is loaded.

Fix (Turns out that the code doesn't even need jQuery!):

```
<div id="note-total">Note Total</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://{name}.tumblr.com/api/read/json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#note-total').append("<br/><br/>" + "this site has total " + tumblr_api_read['posts-total'] + " posts.");
</script>
```

If this turns out to work, I highly encourage you to take a look at why it does.
If it doesn't work, perhaps give a link to your blog where it's not working?

Comment: Thank you for the amended JS, it worked!
I don't know what I was doing wrong before but the code you gave seems to work.
I will experiment with this and try to broaden my knowledge on the subject.
When I get 15 rep points I'll come back and give you an upvote.

Comment: All right, glad to help! As for why your code didn't work, I tried to explain it in my response above. If you have any questions, reply or contact me directly (hint: google).